# Find IP address of client machine

Tags: dns, sas, enterprise-guide

We have a suite of enterprise guide based solutions being run by a small group of people all of whom have different levels of access to shared network resources. The desktop clients are on windows, while the server is Unix. Users only have client installs.

Because of this they all have their own installs of PC Files server (PCFS). The code then instructs the server to connect to &_clientmachine to load the spreadsheet.

However, the network gods have broken the network utility used to convert machine names into IP addresses (the Domain Name Server or DNS). Because of this, the server is failing to convert machine names into IP addresses on a sporadic basis (after resets, sometimes just randomly mid-session.)

While we have PCFS installed on a windows server with a static IP address, it is being run under a secondary account which does not have all the required access to network resources - and granting one account to all the required resources is insecure.

However, I know that PC Files Server can be passed an IP Address instead of a machine name. This means I can keep it running on each users machine, keeping it as secure, while bypassing the lousy DNS.

What I don't know is how to determine the IP address of the client machine. 
(And apparrently no-one on the internet has ever wanted to do it.)

Comment: Fix your nameserver, rather than looking for some half-assorted workaround of the real problem. Invoke the mentioned network gods if necessary. " how to determine the IP address of the client machine" is exactly why nameservers exist.

Comment: @Bushmills I am a very small cog in a big machine. I can raise a ticket about the name server, but that could take weeks to fix. I have users who want to load spreadsheets today.

Comment: Well, if you don't know the ip address, but the name of a machine, you either ask somebody who knows, or you ask a nameserver.

Comment: can you sit behind one of those machines and type in a command, to find out their ip addresses? or is that something you must do remotely?

Comment: I would prefer to be able to do it programmatically using SAS. Unfortunately the code is run on the server. Current plan is to run ipconfig to get the IP address and see if i have access to a hosts-equivalent file on the server...

Comment: If those machines get their network configuration, including their ip addresses, from a DHCP server, that server will have a record of connected machines and their addresses too. How to get that information out of that DHCP server depends. That's actually where nameservers often get the hostname - ip address paring of hosts with dynamic addresses from.

Comment: Or have your users run code on their machine which gets the local IP address and sends it to their remote Unix session.

This is easy in Base SAS (using Local + Remote), here's some help for EG > http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/300-2012.pdf

To get the IP, simply pipe the result of `ipconfig` into a datastep and create a local macro variable containing the IP address. Then use `%SYSLPUT` to copy the macro variable value to the remote server.

Comment: @ChrisJ That looks interesting, thanks. I was under the impression that without a thick install you couldn't run code locally, but I will explore further...

Comment: How about creating a prompt, and having the user copy/paste their IP (from ipconfig) into it?  I agree that if you don't have thick installs the clients probably can't run the code that Chris suggested.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the comment. The change to point the SAS server at the right name server got raised today...